# Displaying Next Element In array when object is clicked AS3 FLASH

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

I currently have a multidimensional array that stores each answer to said array. When the object of the array that is displayed is selected, it should then move onto the next array within the multidimensional array. I've watched a few tutorials and looked up a few answers on this but I still can't figure it out.

This is my multidimensional array:

```
var characterArray:Array = new Array(); 
characterArray[0] = [pirateboy, pirategirl, pig]; //pig is the ans
characterArray[1] = [pirateboy1, pirategirl1 ,parrot1]; //pirateboy is the ans
characterArray[2] = [pirategirl, pirateboy, pirateboy]; //pirategirl is the ans 
characterArray[3] = [parrot1, snowman, parrot1]; //snowman is the ans

var randomnumber = Number; 
randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (characterArray.length));
trace(randomnumber);
```

This is what currently happens when an object is clicked on. I just included this one as an example as they are all the same.

```
pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightanswer); 
function rightanswer (event:MouseEvent){ 
if (MovieClip(event.target) == characterArray[0][2])
{ 
score = score + 5; 
Score_txt.text = (score).toString(); 
setTimeout(DisplayAnswer,1000);
} 
}
```

This is my next question function:

```
characterArray.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextquestion);
function nextquestion(event:MouseEvent){

}
```

I don't know what needs to be put into the function nextquestion in order for it to move onto the element in the array when the object is clicked on.

Comment: Do you want to move `pig` from `characterArray[0]` to `characterArray[1]`?

Comment: Yes, but in random order if that is possible?

Comment: Yes, It's possible. What “random order” means?

Comment: Just when the pig is displayed in characterArray[0], it would move onto one of the other arrays.

Comment: Move to the `characterArray[1]` or the random array?

Comment: Move to the end of the array or the begining?

Comment: Either to be honest, anything at all as long as it moves through the array

Comment: I don't understand. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, cut `pig` from the `characterArray[0]` array.

```
var cuttedPig:MovieClip = characterArray[0].splice(2);
```

Next, choose the random array where `pig` will be pasted.

```
var randomArray:int = Math.round((Math.random() * (characterArray.length-2))+1); // 1, 2 or 3
```

Finally, add the `pig` to the beginning of the random array.

```
characterArray[randomArray].splice(0, 0, cuttedPig);
```

Comment: Ok I see what you're after doing, I will try that. Thanks very much :)